# What is the maximum number of table names under a single schema in a DB2 subsystem?

Tags: sql, database, db2, mainframe, db2-zos

What is the maximum number of results possible from the following SQL query for DB2 on z/OS?

```
SELECT NAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES WHERE TYPE='T' AND CREATOR=? ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

This query is intended to fetch a list of all table names under a specific schema/creator in a DB2 subsystem.

---

I am having trouble finding a definitive answer. According to IBM's "[Limits in DB2 for z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_limits.html)" article, the maximum number of internal objects for a DB2 database is 32767. Objects include views, indexes, etc.

I would prefer a more specific answer for maximum number of table names under one schema. For instance, here is an excerpt from an [IDUG thread](http://www.idug.org/p/fo/et/thread=21567) for a related question:

> Based on the limit of 32767 objects in one database, where each tablespace takes two entries, and tables and indexes take one entry each, then the theoretical max would seem to be, with one tablespace per database,
>   32767 - 2 (for the single tablespace) = 32765 / 2 = **16382 tables**, assuming you need at least one index per table.

Are these assumptions valid (each tablespace takes two entries, at least one index per table)?

Comment: Why not test it?  It shouldn't be too hard to create a bunch of tables in a loop.

Comment: @dan1111 I don't think my db administrator would be happy with me testing this.

Comment: I believe that in DB2 for z/OS, schema != database.  More pertinent, what is the business problem you are trying to solve that gives rise to your apparent belief you will exceed some DB2 for z/OS limit?

Comment: @cschneid I am working on a product that scans the storage landscape of a mainframe environment. The product lets a user configure an active DB2 subsystem SSID on an LPAR. Once configured, the user can select the subsystem and get a list of schemas defined on it, then select a schema and get a list of table names under that schema. I am looking for a reasonable expectation for max number of table names that might show up under a schema.

Answer (score 2):

> assuming you need at least one index per table.

That assumption doesn't seem valid.  Tables don't always have indexes.  And you are thinking about edge cases where someone is already doing something weird, so I definitely wouldn't presume there will be indexes on each table.*

If you really want to handle all possible cases, I think you need to assume that you can have up to 32765 tables (two object identifiers are needed for a table space, as mentioned in the quote).

**Also, the footnote in the documentation you linked indicates that an index takes up two internal object descriptors.  So the math is also incorrect in that quote. It would actually be 10921 tables if they each had an index. But I don't think that is relevant anyway.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your assumptions are appropriate because there are just too many possibilities to consider and in the grand scheme of things probably doesn't make much difference to the answer from your point of view

I'll rephrase your question to make sure I understand you correctly, you are after the maximum number of rows i.e. worst case scenario, that could possibly be returned by your SQL query?

> ### DB2 System Limits
>
> Maximum databases
>
> > Limited by system storage and EDM pool size
>
> Maximum number of databases
>
> > 65217
>
> Maximum number of internal objects for each database
>
> > 32767
>
> The number of internal object descriptors (OBDs) for external objects are as follows
>
> > Table space: 2 (minimum required)
> >
> > > Table: 1
> > >
> > > > Therefore the maximum number of rows from your SQL query:
> > > >
> > > > > 65217 * (32767 - 2) = 2,136,835,005
> > > > >
> > > > > > N.B. DB2 for z/OS does not have a 1:1 ratio between schemas and databases
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > N.N.B. This figure assumes 32,765 tables/tablespace/database i.e. 32765:1:1

I'm sure ±2 billion rows is NOT a "reasonable" expectation for max number of table names that might show up under a schema but it is possible